# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01407: cannot update to NULL in Java

Tags: java, insert, updates, jdbctemplate

I have below code in Java where my `Update` statement is getting failed and i am getting an error `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01407: cannot update ("ORDER_ID_TEST"."SOURCES") to NULL`. I really dont understand why the `SOURCES` field is not getting mapped. I have mentioned only some of the important part of the code. The orderid and other fields are getting mapped in update statement.

The `SOURCES` field is string of not null datatype in table. I am trying to check if combination of ORDERID and EXTORDID exist in table from file then do update or else insert.

Instead of if `(!latestModDate.isEmpty())` if i give ((latestModDate != null)) the process run but its also inserting values and not checking for update statement.

```
@Service
```

public class OImporter {
private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OImporter.class);

```
// Tabellenname auf Spalten in der Tabelle
Map<String, List<ColumnData>> columnDataCache = new HashMap<>();

private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public OImporter(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public void importFile(BufferedReader bufferedReader, String tableName, String fileName,
                       Map<Integer, Function<String, String>> COLUMN_TYPE_MAPPINGS,
                       Map<String, Function<String, String>> COLUMN_NAME_MAPPINGS) throws IOException {
    try {
        importFile(bufferedReader, tableName, fileName, COLUMN_TYPE_MAPPINGS, COLUMN_NAME_MAPPINGS,
                new ArrayList<>());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        log.warn(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: ues columnName.equalsIgnoreCase("SOURCES") and see whether the condition is true or not as your default value is empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle database, an empty string become a `NULL` value.

Assuming `bar` is a `VARCHAR2` column type, the following two statements are the same, i.e. they will set the value to `NULL`.

```sql
UPDATE foo SET bar = ''

UPDATE foo SET bar = NULL
```

Your code fails because local variable `sources` is an empty string.

Since you never declare or initialize `columnName`, it is unclear how that code even compiles, and we cannot tell you why `sources` remains an empty string.

Comment: ok i understood ...now for example i made alter to sources field in database table and remove not null condition...and run process again and now its running fine but the problem is still its not executing Update statement somehow and only inserting duplicate data...is this if condition correct ?  if (!latestModDate.isEmpty())

Comment: @Symonds Since `sources` is an empty string, it is fair to assume that `orderID` might also be an empty string, and since there are likely no records where `ORDERID` is `NULL`, the returned `rowSet` is always empty, and hence `latestModDate` is always empty. Changing `SOURCES` to allow `NULL` values was likely not the correct solution. The problem is: Why are `orderID`, `extOrdId` , and `sources` all null? What value does the defined `columnName` actually have. I highly recommend you **debug** your code, so you can fix the *real* error.

Comment: i am not sure how to change this initialization....String orderID = null, extOrdId = null, sources = "", latestModDate = "";  Because as per your say and also the SOURCES, ORDERID will never be null/empty as i am always receiving values for this fields from file and extOrdId might be null sometimes....in database table now only column LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE is defined as not null...can you please help me here how to handle this initilaization ? thanks

Comment: Can't help you, since I can't see the code that **declares** and **initializes** the `columnName` variable.

Comment: i have added code for complete class now...hope it helps

Comment: did you get any chance to see what can be issue ?

Comment: @Symonds Did you get any chance to **debug** your own code like I previously suggested?